# Spring MVC-Spring security

Tags: spring-security

`web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

`spring-security.xml`:

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

`mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

    <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

am getting followin error

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy' (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Comment: Are you sure the exception says `org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy` instead `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy`?

Comment: @Dani ya its filter chain proxy..

Comment: I mean, the exception should say `org.springframework.security.WEB.FilterChainProxy`, but you wrote `org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy`. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do specify mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml in contextConfiglocation

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Its solves your problem